# Como transformar el codigo en una funcion:

Tags: python, funcion

Como seria la manera de transformar este codigo en una funcion que permita extraer las vocales?

```
alumno1 = "Susana"

vocales = " "
for caracter in alumno1:
    if caracter == "a" or caracter == "e" or caracter == "i" or caracter == "o" or caracter == "u":
        vocales += caracter
```

Answer (score 3):

Yo diría que de la siguiente manera:

```py
def contar_vocales(nombre):
    vocales = ""
    
    for char in nombre: 
        if char.lower() in ['a','e','i','o','u']:
            vocales += char
    
    return vocales
    
print(contar_vocales("Susana"))
```

Comment: Complementando, el `if` se puede definir como: `if char in ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"]:` y así  es más fácil de mantener, por ejemplo agregarle `"A", "E"...` en caso de querer mantener separadas las mayusculas. O si no definirlo como `char.lower()` para aceptar cualquiera.

Comment: Es cierto, lo acabo de editar.